# Deduce that there is a map $f:L/N\times L/N\rightarrow L/N$ such that $[l]*[t] = [l*t]$ for all $l,t$ $\in L$.

Tags: group-theory

Note that it is assumed that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $L$ and $R$ is the equivalence relation on $L$. That is the equivalence class $[l] = l*N:=\{l*n:n \in N\}$ of $l$ in $L$. Where the set $l*N$ is called the left $N$-coset of $l$.

Definition of $R$:
$$R:= \{(l,n)\in L\times L \mid l^{-1}*n\in N\}$$
Additional definition:

$L/N := \{[l]:l\in L\}$, this is the set of equivalence classes for $R$.

Also already proven (thanks to freakish):

That if $(a_1, a_2)$ and $(t_1, t_2)$ both belong to $R$, then $(a_1*t_1,a_2*t_2)\in R$, and $(a_1^{-1},a_2^{-1})\in R$.

All of the the above is assumed because I (and others) have already proven it. Need help with the stated question in the title and below.

Continuation of the question, could not fit on title:

Then also Prove that $(L/N,*)$ is a group with $[l]^{-1}$ = $[l^{-1}]$ for each $l\in L$. I know that this is the quotient of $L$ by $N$.

What I think should happen:

In order to solve the question stated in the title, I am pretty sure I need to prove that the mapping is well-defined and is bijective. But I am not confident. As for the second bit, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This map cannot be bijective if $L/N$ is a finite set. For finite sets there's no bijection between $X\times X$ and $X$. So no, don't go down the "is bijective" road. But yeah, you have to show that it is well defined. And that means that if $aN=a'N$ and $bN=b'N$ then $f(aN, bN)=f(a'N, b'N)$.

---

Indeed, our assumptions imply that $a^{-1}a'\in N$ and $b^{-1}b'\in N$, i.e. $(a, a')\in R$ and $(b, b')\in R$. Thus $(ab, a'b')\in R$ (by the properties of $R$) which means that $$(ab)^{-1}a'b'\in N$$

and this is if and only if $(ab)^{-1}a'b'N=N$ which is if and only if

$$abN=a'b'N$$

This completes the proof.

---

Now that we know that the multiplication is a well defined function put $aN\cdot bN:=f(aN, bN)$. For the second part you need to show that:

1) The multiplication is associative. Indeed

$$aN\cdot (bN\cdot cN)=aN\cdot bcN=abcN=abN\cdot cN=(aN\cdot bN)\cdot cN$$

2) There is a netural element. Indeed the neutral element is simply $eN$ where $e\in L$ is the neutral element of $L$. For any $a\in G$ we have $$aN\cdot eN=aeN=aN=eaN=eN\cdot aN$$

3) We have inverses given by $(aN)^{-1}=a^{-1}N$:

$$a^{-1}N\cdot aN=a^{-1}aN=eN$$
$$aN\cdot a^{-1}N=aa^{-1}N=eN$$

Comment: Yep, thanks for the first bit that all makes sense. The second bit are you testing the given group by the axioms? And why are we doing it for N shouldn't it be for L/N?

Comment: Im testing group axioms for $L/N$. I just use more common notation $aN$ instead of $[a]$.

Comment: @T.Liment Note that cosets $aN$ are elements of $L/N$

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all the help!